# DropDownListFor selected item not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this method to build DropDownList from Enum. SelectListItems are displaying correctly, but Select property not working. I build this code step by step and  items collection has right values with correct Selected item, but DropDownListFor doesn't return right html. I looked for this problem on SO, people had the problem what i do: they had the same names in ViewBag and int the Mode;l property, but I has'nt any ViewBag element. What am I doing wrong?

```
 public static MvcHtmlString EnumDropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
                                                                                Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
                                                                                TEnum selectedValue, object htmlAttributes)
    {

        IEnumerable<TEnum> values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Cast<TEnum>();
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (TEnum e in values)
        {
            var type = typeof(TEnum);
            var memInfo = type.GetMember(e.ToString());
            var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false);
            var name = ((DisplayAttribute)attributes[0]).Name;

            int selected = Convert.ToInt32(selectedValue);
            int cur = Convert.ToInt32(e);

            SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem();
            item.Text = name;
            item.Value = Convert.ToInt32(e).ToString();
            item.Selected = cur == selected;

            items.Add(item);
        }

        return SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(htmlHelper, expression, items, htmlAttributes);
    }
```